# Oracle: object relational database, how to insert table values with foreign key?

Tags: oracle11g

Actually, I have two tables Branch and Account_table and I want to insert the account_table values with a foreign key(bID) values which is primary key in Branch Table (bID) but I am getting errors while inserting values. Following is my code.

```
create type bank_branch as object(
bID varchar2(10),
street varchar2(20),
city varchar2(20),
zipcode varchar2(10),
bPhone varchar2(20))
not final
/
create table branch of bank_branch(
primary key (bID),
/
insert into branch values(
'601','XYZ Street','Orlando','OR112AB','024771169');
/
insert into branch values(
'620','Terrace Road','California','CL229JH','548711131');
/
insert into branch values(
'630','Miami Street','Miami','M21334A','9665411211');
/

create type account_type as object(
accNum int,
accType varchar2(15),
balance number,
bID varchar2(10),
interest number,
overdraftLimit number,
openDate DATE)
/
create table account_table of account_type(
primary key (accNum),
FOREIGN key (bID) REFERENCES branch(bID));
/
insert into account_table 
select 'bID', b.BID
from branch b
where b.BID = 601,
'1001','current','630.87','0.009','400','10-Sep-14');
/
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
create type bank_branch as object(
bID varchar2(10),
street varchar2(20),
city varchar2(20),
zipcode varchar2(10),
bPhone varchar2(20))
not final
/
create table branch of bank_branch(
primary key (bID));
/
insert into branch values(
'601','XYZ Street','Orlando','OR112AB','024771169');
/
insert into branch values(
'620','Terrace Road','California','CL229JH','548711131');
/
insert into branch values(
'630','Miami Street','Miami','M21334A','9665411211');
/

create type account_type as object(
accNum int,
accType varchar2(15),
balance number,
bID varchar2(10),
interest number,
overdraftLimit number,
openDate DATE);
/
create table account_table of account_type(
primary key (accNum),
FOREIGN key (bID) REFERENCES branch(bID));
/
insert into account_table 
select '1001','current','630.87',b.BID,'0.009','400','10-Sep-14'
from branch b
where b.BID = 601;
/
```

1 row(s) inserted.

I have used the same code as yours. Only the insert statement differs. It works fine for me.

Comment: After implementation as per your code
SQL Error: ORA-00913: too many values
00913. 00000 -  "too many values"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: I have used your code only. It works fine for me. One row inserted without any error. I have pasted the entire solution in the answer. Check what you are doing different from the above code. Also if it is not working what is the error you are facing?

Comment: Here we go. Thank allot. Working.